# If $\frac{n_k}{m_k} \rightarrow \xi \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ then $m_k \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that if $\frac{n_k}{m_k} \rightarrow \xi \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ then $m_k \rightarrow \infty$? $m_k$ and $n_k$ are integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For $k$ large enough, we have $\xi-1<\frac {n_k}{m_k}<\xi+1$ and for any $N\in\mathbb N$ there are only finitely many fractions with denominator $\le N$ in this interval. As $\xi$ is not among them, the minimal distance of such a fraction from $\xi$ is positive, say $\epsilon$. As soon as $\left|\frac{n_k}{m_k}-\xi\right|<\epsilon$ we must have $m_k>N$.